# Resume PDF doesn't fully display in certain PDF reader

Tags: pdf

I found a resume online and downloaded to use it for my own resume. However, I'm having problem that certain parts of my resume doesn't display if the PDF reader used is a certain older version (I think). I'm currently using the newest Foxit Phantom PDF and when I tried opening it in Adobe Reader some parts of the resume doesn't display.

I've also had recruiters emailed me saying they couldn't open up my resume so I had to send them a png copy of it. Also, my resume file size is 473KB so sometimes I have trouble uploading my resume since it exceeds the upload file size.

I really like the layout and format of this resume, however with the trouble it's giving me I'm not sure if I should find another resume layout to use or there's some way to fix it. I realized that I probably missed potential interviews since the companies may not be able to open my resume, see it render correctly or I wasn't able to apply since I couldn't upload my resume since it's so big.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to the original source of the resume template? That might be helpful in figuring this out. It's rare to see files that work in PhantomPDF but not Adobe Reader, unless you're using a very old version of Adobe Reader (before 9, for example).

If you're using PhantomPDF, it should have a "Reduce File Size" option. You can try that out and see how well it reduces the size. If it doesn't do enough, you can also try the "Optimize" option, which has options for things like downsampling images.